# Reduce padding in NavigationBar with Material 3

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

I'm using the new Material 3 NavigationBar and NavigationBarItem components, I want the NavigationBar to be thinner, because the default one is too large. I want one similar to the one Gmail or Drive has (see picture at the end for the comparison). Making the icon smaller doesn't work, and neither changing all the available paddings (Icon, NavigationBar and NavigationBarItem).

This is the Composable code, if I change the NavigationBar heigh (using Modifier) then this happens:
[image]

I primarly want to remove the space between the label and the bottom, and the one between the top and the icon.

```
@Composable
fun MyAppBottomBar(navController: NavController, tabs: Array<MenuBottom>) {
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route ?: MenuBottom.INICIO.route
    val rutas = remember { MenuBottom.values().map { it.route } }
    if (currentRoute in rutas) {
        NavigationBar(containerColor = elevation01) {
            tabs.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                NavigationBarItem(
                    selected = currentRoute == item.route,
                    onClick = {
                        if (item.route != currentRoute) {
                            navController.navigate(item.route) {
                                popUpTo(navController.graph.startDestinationId) {
                                    saveState = true
                                }
                                launchSingleTop = true
                                restoreState = true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    label = { Text(stringResource(id = item.title)) },
                    icon = {
                        if (item.route == currentRoute) {
                            Icon(item.selectedIcon, contentDescription = null, tint = Color.Black)
                        } else {
                            Icon(item.unselectedIcon, contentDescription = null)
                        }
                    },
                    colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(
                        selectedIconColor = Color.Black,
                        unselectedIconColor = Color.Black,
                        indicatorColor = Greenyellow,
                        selectedTextColor = Color.Black,
                        unselectedTextColor = Color.Black
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add a Modifier.padding to your text

Comment: @2jan222 i've added modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp) to: Text, NavigationBar, NavigationBarItem and Icon and it looks exactly the same

Answer (score 3):

`NavigationBar` does not use padding. It uses a fixed height. While working with `MUI` (which is a React implementation of Material design) I found that they use a fixed height, and `margin: auto` to center items vertically. Then I figured jetpack compose `NavigationBar` might do the same and the idea was right. The solution is:

```kotlin
NavigationBar(
    modifier = Modifier.height(64.dp)
) {...}
```

Or change it to your taste. It will shrink and grow the space taken up.

Comment: Reducing the overall height will cause text and icon to collide, while still keeping what loos like padding

Answer (score 0):

This most likely has to do with the bottom navigation. The grey bar you see has its own padding by default.

Have a look at [this documentation](https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/) on how to remove those System intents.

Here's what you need to do in a nutshell:

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-insets:<version>"
```

Then in your MainActivity call `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        setContent {...}
    }
```

Now your App should use the entire Screen and your NavigationBar should have the same height as the one from Gmail.

To apply single ones of them again e.g. StatusBar call a modifier:

```
Modifier.statusBarsPadding()
```

Comment: it works, but is there a way to only use it when there is a Bottom Navigation Bar? Using padding in every other screen feels to much work and it'd be better to just quit the padding when using the Bottom Navigation Bar. thanks!!